# Manual Drupal node inserts

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6

I attempted to import images from a custom CMS to Drupal using direct MySQL insert queries to the Drupal database. The images are copied to a path within the drupal site:

```
sites/default/files/images/import
```

The nodes show up in lists but the direct links (someurl/node/1234) cause 404 errors. They are all of type media_image and have a valid uid assigned. I also did associated inserts to `files` and `content_type_media_image`

Is there an internal Drupal process that needs to happen to finalize this import? Is it at all possible without rewriting as a proper Drupal import module?

Sample node insert:

```
INSERT INTO node SET
    type='media_image',
    language='en',
title='apicture.jpg',
uid='4',
status=1,
created=1328644135,
changed=1328644135;

// grab nid as last mysql_insert()
INSERT INTO files SET
uid = 4,
filename = 'apicture.jpg',
filepath = 'sites/default/files/images/import',
filemime = 'image/jpeg',
filesize = 40069,
status = 1,
timestamp = 1328644136;

INSERT INTO content_type_media_image SET
vid = 683,
nid = 683,
field_image_fid = 539,
field_image_list = 1,
field_image_data = 'a:3:{s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:3:"alt";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:0:"";}';
```

Note: the queries above are the generated queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting a 404 it's because the return from the internal [`node_load()` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/6) is NULL/FALSE.

If you step through that function you'll see that an `INNER JOIN` is made from the `node` table to the `node_revisions` table...so if there's no matching record in the `node_revisions` table as far as Drupal's concerned there is no node.

To fix the error you'll just need to populate the `node_revisions` table with its required columns - most notably the `nid` and `vid` (which is the version ID), and title and body. You may also want to set the text format for the body text in the `format` column (it's related to the key in the `filter_formats` table).

Incidentally this version ID should also be added to the `node` table itself, as that's what the `INNER JOIN` is made on. I think the safest way to get the next available ID is:

```
SELECT MAX(vid) + 1 FROM node
```

If you don't have revisions turned on for any content types it's likely the `vid` will always be the same as the `nid` though.

Comment: I did update the vid to be equal to the nid on the rows. Thanks for the info on node_revisions, I'll give that another try today.

Comment: This was indeed the problem for the 404s. I'd give more upvotes if I could. Now on to the next challenge of getting the image to cache.

Answer (score 1):

I think going for direct SQL inserts is a lot too much hassle. Drupal proposes many solutions to import content, my favourite one being Feeds : http://drupal.org/project/feeds. It automates everything, accepts almost any input format and provides very flexible mapping mechanisms.

Going the direct database way means you bypass all the power Drupal provides, and you'll probably reinvent the wheel.

Comment: +1 it definitely makes more sense to use an existing module, or at the very least the in-built API

Comment: Sure, but when you have complex structures and/or input files to reorganize/import, it is clearly faster to perform a manual insertion, because modules (Update, Feeds, etc...) have little bugs that won't let you go trought, unless a new refactoring of your import feeds. Trust me.

Comment: However complex the structure, you need to plan carefully your import and have a deep understanding of the logic of your data. It's as much data analysis as pure technical stuff. Given that fact, I don't see why direct inserts would simplify anything in the process. And you can trust me too on this one ;-D.